# Was it impossible to go into same person's dream each level down, or did it serve a purpose?

Tags: inception

Why did they have to choose a different person each time they went one level deeper in [*Inception*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)?

Couldn't they have kept going into Yusuf's dream all the way down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it comes down to one point - can one mind actively dream two or more states simultaneously.

For the dream within a dream thing to work .... the dreamer in level 1 (Yusuf) has to dream the Pasiv (sleep) machine into existence, in order to allow people to go down to the next level (the hotel dream of Arthur).

For someone to simultaneously be maintaining level 1 *and* be able to go to 'sleep' and maintain level 2 seems unlikely - you'd essentially have to be 'awake' in each dream state.

So it appears for the dream within a dream thing to work, you need as many people to dream as levels you wish to descend.  This appears to be why Cobb wants Yusuf to 'go into the field', as he needs 3 dream levels (Yusuf, Arthur, Eames) - and he does not want to be a dreamer himself (for obvious reasons), and Ariadne was a late addition to the team.

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward that, as you've identified, it would take multiple consciousnesses within a single mind for 'double dreams' to work: so unless someone was schizophrenic, its not going to happen. That's why each 'dreamer' has to stay in their own personal dreamscape: when people pass into another, they lose consciousness in the last. If the dreamer were to lose consciousness, the dream would collapse.

Comment: Except that Cobb and his wife went similarly deep and there were only 2 of them.

Comment: @Izkata - no, Cobb and his wife went into Limbo, unconstructed dreamspace - its not explained how *they* did that - but in the story we see, that can be arranged by dying whilst sedated.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Schizophrenia =/= multiple personality disorder.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon, never claimed Dissociative identity disorder! Schizophrenia can include the splitting of mental function, which would be adequate...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional No, schizophrenia can include the *illusion* of such splitting, which would almost certainly *not* be adequate. Schizophrenia is all about hallucination, and compromised perception. In cases that feature seemingly sentient hallucinations, all of the thinking for all of the "cast of characters" is either being handwaved by the primary's subconscious (hallucinations can seem much more complex than they actually are), or is being done subconsciously by the primary. There's no more or less a second mind actually present than when a novelist invents a book character's actions.

Comment: anyway - as someone with no medical training at all - I think I can safely still say that the vast majority of people could not sustain 2 or more conscious dreams - and this is why they need 1 person per level.

Comment: @iandotkelly The exact methods were not explained (given that there were only 2 of them), but what _was_ explained is that they _did_ go deeper into further dream states until they reached Limbo.